# Function Oracle PL SQL bulk collect error PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE products_type AS OBJECT
(
   products VARCHAR2 (50),
   price VARCHAR2 (50)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE results_type AS TABLE OF products_type;


create or replace get_sum ( l_products in varchar2(50)
   RETURN results_type
IS
   l_result   results_type;
begin
 SELECT distinct products, count(price)
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_result
     FROM products;

   RETURN l_result;
END;
/

DECLARE
    l_result varchar2(50) := '0';
BEGIN
    l_result := get_sum ('apple')
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Price total ' || l_result);
END;
```

I have this table and I want to know what the sum of a product is.
I try to learn how a function works when I want to display more than one column. I found on the internet related to bulk collect and I tried to do so, but I encounter this error:

> PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
> What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `create or replace get_sum` - you forgot keyword function

Comment: Please add expected result. Are you sure you are able to compile the function anyway ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your function `GET_SUM`, you are returning l_result which is of type `results_type`. In your anonymous block, you are calling `GET_SUM` and attempting to assign it to a `VARCHAR2(50)` variable.  The variable you are trying to assign the value to needs to match the return type of the function.